# Any ideas to simplify the awkward rsync expression below?

Tags: bash, ssh, rsync

Here is expression:

```
rsync -avz --progress -e "ssh -i /where/is/my/id_dsa" vivek@some.host:`ssh -i /where/is/my/id_dsa  vivek@some.host "find /remote/source/dir -type f -name '*.sql' | sort -nr | head -1"` .
```

It looks for one fresh SQL file on remote host  **some.host** in **/remote/source/dir** with user **vivek**  and copies to current dir on localhost, it uses `/where/is/my/id_dsa` key for `ssh` and `rsync` authorization.

So  this backquoted `ssh -i ...` frightens me a lot. But I don't see other way to find necessary file. How can I simplify it?

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify the command by adding configuration below into your .ssh/config:

```
    host some.host
        identityfile /where/is/my/id_dsa
        user vivek
```

Now your command would be simply

```
rsync -avz --progress -e "ssh some.host:`ssh some.host "find /remote/source/dir -type f -name '*.sql' | sort -nr | head -1"` .
```

Usually I prefer --partial --progress than --progress, and it has a shorter option 'P',
so your command would be

```
rsync -avzPe "ssh some.host:`ssh some.host "find /remote/source/dir -type f -name '*.sql' | sort -nr | head -1"` .
```

If you keep all sql files those has been transferred in the past in current directory, no need to choose files to be transferred selectively, because rsync will do comparison for you and won't retransfer existing files. So your command can be simplified further to

```
rsync -avzPe "ssh some.host:`ssh some.host "find /remote/source/dir -type f -name '*.sql'"` .
```

And last, you can use rsync's filter rule for your command

```
rsync -avzP some.host:/remote/source/dir/**/*.sql .
```

Please be careful to use command above, because subdirectory structure will be stripped out. Try running it with --dry-run first. Notice also that you don't need -e ssh blah, because single ':' will automatically tell rsync to use ssh instead. Let me know if this does not satisfy your need.

Cheers!

Comment: Yes, it's useful.

But content of source file as well as content of destination is upredictable, since I use selective transfer

Answer (score 0):

First, you can simplify the SSH commands by adding an alias to your [`~/.ssh/config`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5) file.

```
Host somehost
HostName some.host
User vivek
IdentityFile /where/is/my/id_dsa
```

On to the main meat: you need to perform two steps, first determine which file to copy (which must be done on the remote side), then copy or update that file. It would be easier if you didn't have to worry about which files are remote and which ones are local. So mount the remote filesystem with [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html).

```
mkdir somehost
sshfs somehost:/ somehost
```

You can now act entirely on local files. You should probably pass the `--no-whole-file` option to `rsync`, because otherwise it assumes that a local filesystem is fast and will always copy the whole file rather than apply its incremental delta algorithm.

```
rsync -avz --progress --no-whole-file $(find somehost/remote/source/dir -type f -name '*.sql' | sort -nr | head -1) .
```

Now, rather than call `find`, use zsh as your shell. Like most `find` calls, yours can be replaced by a few [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers): `.` for `-type f`, `On` for a numerical sort, and `[1]` to keep only the first match.

```
rsync -avz --progress --no-whole-file somehost/remote/source/dir/**/*.sql(.on[1]) .
```